# Include/exclude for visibility graphics of linked models

Tags: revit-api

Is anyone aware of any changes to the Revit API (or other workarounds) to be able to adjust the “include/exclude” for visibility graphics of linked models with Dynamo?

I’m looking for a way to be able to manipulate the visibility of let’s say a linked structural or architectural model floor plan within my host MEP model; to turn on/off certain parameters in the Revit Link tab for Model Categories and/or Annotation Categories. Also of interest is the ability to turn on/off the Halftone and/or Underlay option for Revit Links.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cross-posted in the Dynamo forum at: https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/include-exclude-for-visibility-graphics-of-linked-models/42068

Answer (score 0):

no not yet, not even via Revit API :( 
[See this link](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-ideas/set-the-by-linked-view-property-of-a-view-in-the-api/idi-p/6918662?search-action-id=450724418705&search-result-uid=6918662)